# Removing string from search filter made with Jquery

Tags: jquery, search, replace

I'm using this script to filter results in a table. The problem is that phone numbers are formatted xxx-xxx-xxxx, and when you search if you omit the hyphen the search will miss the entry. Is there any way to ignore the hyphens with the search? I've tried modifying the line that omits the spaces but I can't get it to work at all. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $orders = $('#orders tbody .filter');
    $('#filtersearch').keyup(function () {
        var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        $orders.closest('tr').hide().each(function () {
            if ($('td', this).filter(function () {
                var text = $(this).text().replace(/-\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
                return text.indexOf(val) != -1;
                s
            }).length > 0) $(this).show();
        })
    });
    $('#filtersearch').keyup();
});
```

And my code for the

```
        // connect to the database
        include('connect-db.php');


        // get results from database
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders ORDER BY Name ASC") 
                or die(mysql_error());  

        // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

         // echo out the contents of each row into a table
                echo "<tr>";
                echo '<td>' . $row['date'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td class="filter">' . $row['Name'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td class="filter">' . $row['Company'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td class="filter">' . $row['Phone'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td><img src="images/icons/'.$row['Location'].'.png"></td>';
                echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '"><img src="images/icons/checkmark.png"></a></td>';
                echo "</tr>"; 
        } 


?>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

`999-999-999".replace(/-\s+/g, ' ')` will check for *both* a hyphen and a whitespace character. Use this to check for either one:

```
"999-999-999".replace(/[-\s]+/g, ' ')  // "999 999 999"
```